# Check from web page if ClickOnce app is installed, without user interaction

Tags: windows, browser, clickonce

I'm working on the UX for a web application with a desktop component to interact with files. The app presents the user with a 3-step process (3 buttons), the second button is 'Install app'.

In case the user has already installed the ClickOnce app before, I want to hide this step so I don't have to bother the user with this.

My questions:

(1) is this possible

If so,

(2) how can it be done

(3) do I also need to check if the clickonce app is running in order to interact with it from the browser/server?

Thanks already for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) I don't believe the answer to this question needs to be unique for ClickOnce applications. The same answers provided at [What is the best way for a website to check if a user has installed a client app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159476/what-is-the-best-way-for-a-website-to-check-if-a-user-has-installed-a-client-app) would apply. I like the answer about using a protocol the best.

3) No.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I like the approach with a protocol too, especially because it also works on Mac. We played with protocols on another project some time ago.. Then it presented the user an unfamiliar dialog asking confirmation when registering the protocol during setup - How can a one-click user experience be achieved without questions that might make a user hesitate/be uncertain?